# What have I done wrong? I've tried diffchecker to see the difference between them. (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I don't see the reason that while I can update user0's balance, and it works perfectly fine. However, if I try to update admin's balance, it returns with a TypeError of Cannot read property 'save' of null. If you need more code, please tell me and I will give you the code.

Here's my code: (user0's)

```
app.post("/my/user0/update", isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.balance || req.body.freebalance === null) {
        res.redirect("/my/user0")
    }
    if (req.body.balance >= 0) {
        const newBal = req.body.balance
        const updateDB = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: "user0" }, { balance: newBal }, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Something went wrong.")
            }
        })
        await updateDB.save()
    } else if (req.body.freebalance >= 0) {
        const newBal = req.body.freebalance
        const updateDB = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: "user0" }, { freebalance: newBal }, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("something went wrong.")
            }

            console.log(doc)
        })
        await updateDB.save()
    }
})
```

admin's code (the chunk that doesn't work)

```
app.post("/admin/update", isAdmin, async (req, res) => {
    if (req.body.balance || req.body.freebalance === null) {
        res.redirect("/admin")
    }
    if (req.body.balance >= 0) {
        const newBal = req.body.balance
        const updateDB = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: "admin" }, { balance: newBal }, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Something went wrong.")
            }

            console.log(doc)
        })
        await updateDB.save()
    } else if (req.body.freebalance >= 0) {
        const newBal = req.body.freebalance
        const updateDB = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: "admin" }, { freebalance: newBal }, { new: true }, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("something went wrong.")
            }

            console.log(doc)
        })
        await updateDB.save()
    }
})
```

EJS: (for user0's ejs, there's no difference except for the h1 being Update user0's balance)

```
<% layout("boilerplate.ejs") %>
    <div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <h1>Update Admin Balance</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/">Back</a>
        <form action="/admin/update/" method="POST">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="balance">New Balance</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="balance" name="balance" value="balance">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="freebalance">New Free Balance</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="freebalance" name="freebalance" value="freebalance">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3"><button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button></div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of updateDB in admin's code? Is it null? Seems like no record is found hence its null.

Comment: Mongoose should automatically save your changes when you use `findOneAndUpdate()`. Try removing `await updateDB.save()`.

Comment: Ok... I've checked the value of updateDB, it's not null.

Comment: I've tried it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried it, it still doesn't work. UPDATE: yep, it doesn't exist. But the thing is, I've literally created it. Seee here: ```d = new User({
        username: "user0",
        carePlan: "free",
        password: "user0password",
        balance: 0,
        freebalance: 1
    })
    a = new User({
        username: "admin",
        isPremium: true,
        isTester: true,
        carePlan: "MVP++",
        password: "adminpassword",
        balance: 0,
        freebalance: 0,
        isAdmin: true
    })``` then I tried findOne(ing) them and user0 was fine but admin return nul